# Mayavi integration in PyQt5: Meaning of class

Tags: python, class, pyqt5, mayavi

I found a way to integrate a mayavi plot into a pyqt5 gui.

```
import os
os.environ['ETS_TOOLKIT'] = 'qt5'

from traits.api import HasTraits, Instance, on_trait_change
from traitsui.api import View, Item
from mayavi.core.ui.api import MayaviScene, MlabSceneModel, \
        SceneEditor
################################################################################
#The actual visualization
class Visualization(HasTraits):
    scene = Instance(MlabSceneModel, ())

    @on_trait_change('scene.activated')
    def update_plot(self):
        # This function is called when the view is opened. We don't
        # populate the scene when the view is not yet open, as some
        # VTK features require a GLContext.

        # We can do normal mlab calls on the embedded scene.
        self.scene.mlab.test_points3d()

    # the layout of the dialog screated
    view = View(Item('scene', editor=SceneEditor(scene_class=MayaviScene),
                     height=250, width=300, show_label=False),
                resizable=True # We need this to resize with the parent widget
                )
```

QWidget containing the visualization, this is pure PyQt4 code.

```
class MayaviQWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0,0,0,0)
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.visualization = Visualization()

        # If you want to debug, beware that you need to remove the Qt
        # input hook.
        #QtCore.pyqtRemoveInputHook()
        #import pdb ; pdb.set_trace()
        #QtCore.pyqtRestoreInputHook()

        # The edit_traits call will generate the widget to embed.
        self.ui = self.visualization.edit_traits(parent=self,
                                                 kind='subpanel').control
        layout.addWidget(self.ui)
        self.ui.setParent(self)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Don't create a new QApplication, it would unhook the Events
    # set by Traits on the existing QApplication. Simply use the
    # '.instance()' method to retrieve the existing one.
    app = QtGui.QApplication.instance()
    container = QtGui.QWidget()
    container.setWindowTitle("Embedding Mayavi in a PyQt4 Application")
    # define a "complex" layout to test the behaviour
    layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(container)

    # put some stuff around mayavi
    label_list = []
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if (i==1) and (j==1):continue
            label = QtGui.QLabel(container)
            label.setText("Your QWidget at (%d, %d)" % (i,j))
            label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignHCenter|QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
            layout.addWidget(label, i, j)
            label_list.append(label)
    mayavi_widget = MayaviQWidget(container)

    layout.addWidget(mayavi_widget, 1, 1)
    container.show()
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    window.setCentralWidget(container)
    window.show()

    # Start the main event loop.
    app.exec_()
```

My question: since I am kind of a beginner in python I do not really understand what the class visualization() is for? Is there a way do get the code run without creating this class. 
I am asking because I have an existing gui where I would like to integrate a mayavi plot. Before there was a plot made with matplotlib and canvas...So I used this code as base for embedding the plot to my gui. I removed the class Visualization but it get the error: `AttributeError: 'MainWindow' object has no attribute 'trait_view'`. I think it is searching for trait_view within my class "MainWindow". I don't understand why, because I didn't use the attribute 'trait_view'....

Answer (score 0):

It actually looking for `view` through `trait_view`.

`traits` is a library that provides typed members by calling pre and post functions when accessing members. Not only that, but a extendable way of interacting with these traits through python code and even GUI widgets (more info [here](https://docs.enthought.com/traits/))

You need the Visualization to provide user interactivity with GUI widgets through these traits.